# W10 - Upgraded from Home to Pro, now crashes on Standard Account

Tags: windows-10, freeze, group-policy, standard-user

Yesterday I decided to upgrade my W10 Home PC to W10 Pro, in an effort to lock down the machine with GPO and use other features. The upgrade was fine and seemed to complete without issues in around 5 minutes so I was impressed.

However I then decided to create a standard profile for other people to use and started to employ simple policies through GPO, such as restrict running firefox.exe and chrome.exe. Nothing major.

When I tried to test this out by switching to the Standard account it firstly hung on the 'Intro' screen for new profiles. I had to kick the PC and reboot. It logged me straight back into the Standard profile, but then explorer hung and I had to reboot. A third time did it the same, but I was able to CTRL-ALT-DEL and log off the profile and into my Admin account which worked fine. No freezing, no hanging. I've replicated a bunch of times and each time the Admin account is fine, but the Standard account freezes.

I'm not sure if it's a driver issue, or something I may have done on the GPO, or whether it's W10 Pro related. But it's a real pain and renders the update pretty useless.

I've tried creating the Standard account through the User Accounts in Control Panel and through Users in MMC, no different.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out it was my Razer keyboard causing issues. I tried loading the profile with the keyboard plugged in/pulled out a few times, and each time it was out the Standard profile loaded. When it was plugged in it froze.

Doesn't answer the question as to 'why', as I'd updated the drivers/rolled them back to no avail. Plus it worked fine on Windows 10 Home. I've resorted to using a new keyboard instead.